# What, why or when it is better to choose a queuing tool vs database task table?

Tags: queueing

I would like to know what, why or when it is better to choose a queuing tool and what, why or when it is better to choose database task table? I don't understand the difference of sending my tasks in a queuing tool or in a database table that will be read and act as a queue. Is there some properties that queuing tools has that database cannot do?

Read my question as "what are the benefit or what are the arguments to choose a queuing tool solution". My question is not about what language, technology, or project one should take up next.

Thank you,

Comment: Hello B413, it really helps us to answer your question if you would follow the advice from http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask and tell us which kind of research you have done so far, what you have found and why it didn’t meet your needs. AFAIK you have already asked a similar question here (which was closed), where I gave you some tutorial links to some queuing tools. Did you read them?

Comment: Yes I read them. I really don't understand what a queuing tools do better than a database. Sorry but for me every thing listed in queuing tool pros : Transactional, Durable, Reliable, Distributed, Scalable are the same properties than a database. And a queuing tool seems to require a database. So why using a queuing tool? If someone can give me a real example where a database is not enough.

Comment: Well, for one, the DB will not warn your logic when a new message is available. And will not distribute the messages between several consumers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is queues are optimized for what they do while databases are not.  Some actually consider the use of [a database as a queue](http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/programming-life/a-look-at-using-your-database-as-a-queue-49143) [an anti-pattern](http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2012/04/database-as-queue-anti-pattern.html).  [Much has been said](https://www.google.com/search?q=dont+use+a+database+as+a+queue&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS566US567&oq=dont+use+a+database+as+a+queue&aqs=chrome..69i57.7584j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=database+as+a+queue&safe=off) that I won't repeat here.  A common thought is that while it seems trivial to turn a database into a queue, you eventually end up having to solve all of the problems the queue designers have already solved for you.